# Embedded youtube video not playing in some Android devices

Tags: android, video, youtube, embed, android-youtube-api

I built an Android app to watch online courses using videos from Youtube. Since the courses are paid, the videos are unlisted on Youtube and I was using [this](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) library to prevent the users from share the video link.

About 1% of my users were unable to play the videos and receiving this error:VIDEO_NOT_PLAYABLE_IN_EMBEDDED_PLAYER, but the video embedding is allowed.

I thought that it was a library bug so I replaced it with a webview loading a website using plyr.io to play the videos.
The same error is happening (for only 1% of my users) and I have no idea why. It happens on all Android versions, all the users are in the same country and I didn't set any restriction on the youtube videos.

I'm struggling with that for days and I cannot find a good explanation. Maybe a youtube restriction that I'm not seeing? Or a youtube bug?

I hope someone can provide me an explanation about it.
Feel free to ask for more details or share some code.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? Encountering the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you may read below:

https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions_28.html

> A video that is embeddable but not syndicatable will play on YouTube.com or on other sites that embed the YouTube player, but may not play on devices such as mobile phones or TVs. If you’d like to learn more about retrieving videos suitable for playback on mobile devices, see the developer’s guide.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. How can the same video be playable for one user and not playable for another if both are using the same app in the same place? Youtube really needs to make that more clear. My app is useless for some users that paid to watch the content! I think that I will have to host my videos anywhere else